# Solr search now showing some posts

Tags: solr

I am using solr search.

If i am trying to find something by this "*urs meister Service public*" it's dosen't show me this post `http://www.avenir-suisse.ch/15068/mehr-markt-fur-den-service-public/`

But if i am using this "*urs meister **den** Service public*" it's working.
How can i make it work with this "*urs meister Service public*"?

The problem only in one word.
I can add my schema.xml if this help

Comment: Yes please add some parts of your schema: what kind of fieldtype do you use?

Comment: I am using "text" field   `<field name="title" type="text_lws" indexed="true" stored="true"/>   <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

Comment: There are couple of things to check here. 1) What is your default search field defined in solrconfig.xml; if it is only author and title and the value mentioned above comes in author filed then this is an expected behavior. With string field type only exact/wild card search will work. Use text field type for partial search

Comment: I am using this service for the solr  [link](http://www.gotosolr.com/en/)  
I can't check solrconfig.xml. I can only upload schema.xml to this service.  
In schema.xml i have a lot of fields. But i can't post all of them here. I can pay if some one will resolve this problem